# MacOS: Can I specify a file path that points to randomized (or specific files)?

Tags: macos, directory, filepath, finder

I am using simple program that asks for a supplied file path to play a sound file.

I have a folder called Sounds with some files:

```
Downloads/Sounds/001.mp3
Downloads/Sounds/002.mp3
Downloads/Sounds/003.mp4
```

Currently I have selected 001.mp3 in the program.

**In macOS, is there any way to specify, either in the program file path line, or as a script of some sort, which will allow selection of one random (or user-defined, i.e, file that fit a certain criteria) file from this folder automatically?  Such that each time the sound plays it uses a different file?**

For example, I imagine the solution would be something along the lines of:

```
Downloads/Sounds/{filename: ANY, type: .mp3}
```

or

```
Downloads/Sounds/{filename: ANY, type: .mp3, tag: "RED"}
```

or

```
Downloads/Sounds/{filename: ANY, type: .mp4}
```

etc.

If not, any other workarounds to this would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear, to me at least. Do you want a random file or one that fits a certain criterion? What happens when you run it for the 4th time and you only have 3 files? What's the *"tag"* supposed to be?

Comment: Hi there.  I want a random file as the source every time the sound plays in the program.  (The sound plays during a program event, such as a process successfully completing.) For my purposes, I'm not concerned with the order of the sounds, just so long as *a* sound is played. Tag is just a simple category marker in macOS.

Comment: It's still very unclear to me. Are you talking about Applescript, bash, Python, Perl, Swift? Do you know how to get a list of all files in that directory? Do you know how to count the files in the list? Do you know how to generate a random number less than the number of files? Why don't you play file1 the first time, file2 the second time you need one and so on?

Comment: Hey Mark.  I should edit my question as it’s pretty unclear.  I’m not writing any code.  I am **using** another program.  So, I’m wondering if I can accomplish the task by simply supplying some sort of string in the file path, OR some script inside the Sounds folder which would generate a different file, etc...

Comment: Tell the other app to always play `selected.mp3`. Then, outside the app use symbolic links to make `selected.mp3` point to one of the actual tracks, e.g. in Terminal run `ln -s 001.mp3 selected.mp3` and then `ls -l` to see that `selected.mp3` now points to `001.mp3`